# Vue3 component does not call onMounted hook

Tags: synchronization, pivot, laravel-8

Project is Vue3 + Typescript + composition api. I have pretty simple component which contains onMounted() hook which should set up some properties after data change. Parent component make API request and then send ned data vie props to child component. I expected that the component will call onMounted again and will setup properties but it is not. This is the child compmonent code.

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
    import Iconbase from '@/components/icons/Iconbase.vue'
    import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

    interface Option {
        title: string
        value: number
    }

    const emits = defineEmits(['selected'])
    const open = ref(false)
    const defaultValue = ref<Option>()

    const props = defineProps({
      status: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
      },
      options: {
          type: Array as () => Option[],
          required: true
      },
      selectable: {
          type: Boolean,
          require: true
      }
    })

    function openSelect() {
        if (props.selectable) {
            open.value = !open.value
        }
    }

    function setActiveValue(item: Option) {
        defaultValue.value = item
        emits('selected', item.value)
    }

    onMounted(() => {
        defaultValue.value = props.options.find((option: Option) => {
            console.log('DisplayStatus.onMounted()');
            if (option.value === props.status) return option
        })
    })
</script>
```